# Django - bulk_create objects with order_with_respect_to attribute

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

Hi I have list of model objects: `my_objects`, which should be saved in a databse.
This model has `order_with_respect_to` property in its `Meta` class.

When I try to `bulk_create` this list I got:

> null value in column "_order" violates not-null constraint" during bulk_create

When I just iterate over elements and invoke `save()` on every each of them. Everything is fine, but such sequential database access doesn't satisfy me...

I've tried to invoke `signals.pre_save.send` function, but this didn't change the situation.

This worked when I've invoked `_save_table`, on every signle element from `my_objects`, but `_save_table` is the heaviest part of `save()` method, so I gained nothing...

Is there a possibility to save batch of django objects with only one database connection?

I'm using `postgresql`.

Comment: I'm wordering about the same question. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a field and you can set "_order" manually or calculate that before bulk_create.

```py
# Model
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

# Bulk create example
# Data
product_data_list = [{"name": "Apple"}, {"name": "Potato"}]

# Add "_order" field for each product
for index, product_data in enumerate(product_data_list):
    product_data["_order"] = index

# Create
Product.objects.bulk_create(Product(**product_data) for product_data in product_data_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

If the model’s primary key is an AutoField it does not retrieve and set the primary key attribute, as save() does.

I am guessing that your id was on autoincrement and now it isn't being saved, which is being referenced by _order.